# How can I stop the new PHP logo spinning at the top of the php.net pages once and for all?

Tags: php

Update: Doing a hard refresh as per @larsAnders's suggestion results in a new icon - they're cycled.

It is doing my head in.

This is a serious issue with the potential to adversely effect global internet experience by lowering code quality for at least two reasons:

- It can make you close the browser window too quickly resulting in misunderstanding what's on the page. This effect disproportionately effects short pages and information near the top of longer pages;
- It can lead to an overwhelming temptation for some to look for help on sites such as W3Schools. (So far I've not succumbed to that.)

Please note, it does appear to stop spinning after a while, but this is only after madness starts to set in resulting in my observation that it had actually stopped being unreliable.

Comment: Um... what?  [It doesn't spin...](http://php.net/)

Comment: What is, exactly, your question?

Comment: Try looking at http://uk1.php.net/docs.php

Comment: ...late April Fool's Day gag?

Comment: It was spinning yesterday, but I'm not seeing that today. Probably just do a hard refresh by holding down Shift.

Comment: @Gwenc37 or could it be malware? But why?

Comment: @DissidentRage It's April 2

Comment: It's not malware, it's an obviously late April Fool's gag.

Comment: @patricksweeney Hope so

Answer (score 0):

They changed the logo again.
Kill your cash with CTRL+SHIFT+DEL oder refresh with SHIFT+F5

The animated one was really annoying...